# Batch script to rename a file multiple times

Tags: time, batch-file, rename

I am trying to do a batch script that will be a a on/off switch for a shutdown script.

Basically to switch the shutdown script that runs on task schedule on and off by renaming it. So I have two options for it one that renames it from its original name to something else to stop the task schedule triggering and the other to switch it back on by changing the name to the original one.

Now, this works once, but if I try to do it again nothing happens.

Where am I going wrong?

:Option1

```
rename C:\Users\user\Desktop\shutdown.bat shutdown1.bat
```

:Option2

```
rename C:\Users\user\Desktop\shutdown1.bat shutdown.bat
```

Comment: We need more info. Can you show us the entire batch file?

Comment: Hi this is the entir batch file

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have posted your code as answer...

The problem is that you are not skipping `:Selection2` when `Selection1` is choose. You must put `GOTO :Quit` before `:Selection2`

Answer (score 0):

Heres the whole code

```
@ECHO OFF
C:
CD\
CLS

:MENU
CLS

ECHO ============= MENU NAME =============
ECHO Select an option from below by typing the corresponding number.
ECHO _
ECHO 1.  Turn ON Auto Night Shutdown
ECHO 2.  Turn OFF Auto Night Shutdown
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO ==========PRESS 'Q' TO QUIT==========
ECHO.

SET INPUT=
SET /P INPUT=Please select a number:

IF /I '%INPUT%'=='1' GOTO Selection1
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='2' GOTO Selection2
IF /I '%INPUT%'=='Q' GOTO Quit

CLS

ECHO ============INVALID INPUT============
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO Please select a number from the Main
echo Menu [1-2] or select 'Q' to quit.
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO ======PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE======

PAUSE > NUL
GOTO MENU

:Selection1

rename C:\Users\user\Desktop\shutdown.bat shutdown1.bat 

 :Selection2

rename C:\Users\user\Desktop\shutdown1.bat shutdown.bat

 :Quit
  CLS

  ECHO ==============SUCCESS===============
  ECHO -------------------------------------
  ECHO ======PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE======

  PAUSE>NUL
   EXIT
```

Comment: Warning: You are clearing screen and acknowledging user of successful operation without checking operation result! I would recommend you to 1) check operation result before displaying success messages or 2) allow error messages be shown.

Comment: Thank you for the tip I have rewritten the code and it is working properly, but I will need to work on the error control as you say. This can be marked as resolved.